# there was an error loading this feature. try restarting the profiler to fix it

Tags: android, android-studio, memory

Android Studio is trying to use the profiler to analyse memory jitter, using `Record Java/Kotlin allocations`. But I was prompted `there was an error loading this feature. try restarting the profiler to fix it`.

[image]

After I press the `Record` button, AS stays at the `Setting up allocation tracking` screen.

[image]

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.11005911, built on October 26, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.1.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.github.copilot (1.4.0.3748)
    name.kropp.intellij.makefile (223.8214.6)
    com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.12)
    com.aone.copilot (1.1.7)
```

```
Android 9.
```

Works properly and allows me to analyse the memory jitter. Or tell me the cause of the error.

I would be very grateful if you could tell me any alternative way to analyse the memory jitter.

Thanks♪(･ω･)ﾉ